# Creating a variable number of list in Python

Tags: python

I want to read data from a .txt file and enter each column as a variable (say x_1, x_2, etc)
Normally I use

```
x_1, x_2, x_3 = numpy.loadtxt('filename.txt', delimiter=',' , unpack = True)
```

Now the problem is each data file is going to have different number of columns. So I was looking for a way to create multiple variable names x_i

I tried using a dictionary with each key as an empty list in the following way:

```
features = dict(('x_%d' %i,[]) for i in range (1,n))   # n is specified by user
```

The problem is I want to convert these lists(x_1, x_2, etc into a matrix and carry out some matrix operations later. And I just cannot refer these keys as variables as in:

```
x_1.T                        # Transpose  OR
x_2 - Y                      # both x_2 and Y are matrices
```

And I don't want to use something like features['x_3'] every time. Any suggestions?

**update:** Okay found out a way: create a list of matrices and then refer to them as x[o], x[1], etc. Even though x is a list, x[2] is a matrix.

Any better/smarter solution?

Comment: You can utilize the `locals()` method. It'd be okay for smaller scripts and applications but it gets unruly fast IMO.

Comment: What's wrong with just using a 2 dimensional list? so you'd do `x = numpy.loadtxt(...)` and then `x[0].T`, `x[1] - Y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a list called x instead?

```
x[1].T
x[2] - Y
```

It's only one extra keystroke compared to `x_1`, `x_2`, etc. If you don't want to use `x[0]`, just put a `None` there.

Dynamically generating local or global varibles is a bad idea.

Comment: @ Lauritz: Yes exactly this is what I did as mentioned in my update, thanks anyways for the fast reply

Answer (score 1):

First load the file into a big array (matrix):

```
x = numpy.loadtxt('filename.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
```

Now you can access the column vectors with

```
x1 = x[:,0]
x2 = x[:,1]
```

and use numpy functions on these variables

```
y = x1.dot(x2)
```